# When to use which Layouts in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

So I have been writing some Android code for a week or two and some layouts are self-explanatory such as gird, table, and so on. However, I am still confused about when to use Linear layouts, when to use Constraint Layouts and when shall I use Relative Layouts. I know that Google prefers Constraint layouts but, a lot of code samples use other kinds of Layouts. I am confused if I shall even prefer other kinds of layouts or not?

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to get the less nesting in your layout as possible, this for performance, if the layout is quite simple and show a vertical or horizontal layout, I will use **LinearLayout**, otherwise I will use **ConstraintLayout** because it's the more powerful layout and any layout can be implemented with **ConstraintLayout** even the simple ones and it's the evolution of **RelativeLayout**, also android recommends to use that layout.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. I did read the documentation for an hour or so to understand what you meant by Constraint layouts are powerful. I agree with your view